# change text of tlf text field from jsfl

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, jsfl

How can I set/change the text of tlf Text Field using jsfl. Apparently .setTextString() only works for classic text fields.

Comment: ouch! Noticed your not having any luck on the Adobe forums :( You need support from Adobe staff, since they didn't expose/document anything on TLF. if you do fl.trace(fl.getDocumentDOM().selection[0].elementType); with your TLF instance it will print out "tlfText" ,inspecting the selection with a for...in loop only reveals the variables, not functions, which isn't very useful.

Comment: How can I get support from Adobe staff ? Any ideas ? I also tried what you said, but to no luck.

Answer (score 0):

No APIs were added for TLF. You can request that Adobe add that functionality to the next release here:
https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform